# Optimizing a WHERE clause with a dateadd function

Tags: t-sql

For the business that I am working in I would like to get information on our customers. The base information I have on these customers is as follows:

- `Activation_Date` stored in a `Loans` table, datatype is `datetime`.
- `ActivityDate` stored in a `CustomerDailyLoanActivity_Information` table (a daily loans table to those interested, it is part of a datamart and stores for *each* day that a customer has been active with our company how much they have paid into their loan, so if a customer has an `Activation_Date` of 15-03-2017, it has `ActivityDate`s in the `CustomerDailyLoanActivity_Information` table from 15-03-2017 up until now whereby each `ActivityDate` has a record in another column `Sum_Paid_To_Date` how much has been paid up until that `ActivityDate`). Datatype of `ActivityDate` is `date`.

What I would like to know is the following, I would like to know how much each customer has paid on 1, or 2, or 3, etc. months after his `Activation_Date`. So the query would look something like the following (slightly pseudo-code, the more important part is the `WHERE` clause).

```
SELECT
cldai.Sum_Paid_To_Date,
cldai.ActivityDate,
cldai.Customer_Account_Number
FROM
CustomerLoanDailyActivity_Information cldai
INNER JOIN 
Loans l ON l.Customer_Account_Number = cldai.Customer_Account_Number
WHERE
  (cldai.ActivityDate = CAST(l.Activation_Date AS date)
   OR
   cldai.ActivityDate = DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(l.Activation_Date AS date)) 
   OR
   cldai.ActivityDate = DATEADD(month, 2, CAST(l.Activation_Date AS date))
   OR
   cldai.ActivityDate = DATEADD(month, 3, CAST(l.Activation_Date AS date)) 
   )
ORDER BY
l.Customer_Account_Number, cldai.ActivityDate ASC
```

So the problem is that this query is really really slow (because of the WHERE clause and because the `cldai` table is big (~6 GB)) and exits before any data is retrieved. A couple of problems that I have heard, and possible solutions, but haven't worked so far.

- The CAST function makes the query really slow because it does a comparison with the `ActivityDate` column, which is indexed. I used CONVERT before but that was also really slow. I feel like I need to do the convert/cast though, because the `ActivityDate` is of `date` type and the `Activation_Date` is of `datetime` type, so there is a possibility that the time part of the `datetime` in `Activation_Date` will cause there to be no matches with the `ActivityDate` (e.g. `Activation_Date` for a given customer is 15-03-2017 09:00:00 so it will never match with `ActivityDate` 15-03-2017 because this might be converted to `datetime` 15-03-2017 00:00:00, which will never be equal because of the `time` part).
- I have to use "DateTime" evaluations, which has been suggested as a solution, but I have no clue on how to apply this correctly.
- I can't look at the execution plan because the DBA has blocked me from seeing that.

Any ideas on how to make this query perform more quickly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So a massive speedup was obtained by using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` and by not ordering the data on the server but on the client side. This reduced the query time from about an hour and 10 minutes to about 1 minute. It seems unbelievable but it's what happened.

Regards,

Tim.

Comment: Thanks for posting the resolution. You should accept your answer if you can. Also if you could persuade the DBAs to send you an image of the query plans it would be very interesting to understand why the left join is so much quicker.

Comment: They will give me access to the plan yes, so as soon as I can do that I will. Can only accept my own answer after 48 hours so still waiting on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are guaranteed to have a record for each day, you could apply use the row_number() function to apply row numbers for each group of customer loan repayment records, and then retrieve rows 1,31,61 and 91? This would avoid any date manipulation.

Comment: Hi Hedley, this could work but I forsee two problems (but correct me if I'm being too pessimistic): 1. We would have to know the start row of each customer in the CLDAI table, which would require some sort of lookup. 2. We would have to have the number of row be dependent on the number of days in the month that the customer activated in, which would be different for all customers basically (not mentioning customers who activate on 31st of January, whose first +1 month date would fall on 28th of February).

Comment: Just to add to that, I don't think the table is sorted by Customer_Loan_Number and then by ActivityDate, but simply dumps the new rows for each ActivityDate at the end of the table (which would increase in size every day too, since we are continually adding new customers)

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting this up into two steps? Step one - build a table with the four dates for each customer. Then step two, join this to your main CustomerLoanDailyActivity_Information table on date and customer account number. The second step would have a much simpler join, just an = between the ActivityDate and date entry in the table you have built.

Comment: Thanks Hedley, but unfortunately I can't build my own tables in the database, but if I could it would be a good solution yes!